# java - compare BigInteger with BigDecimal

Tags: java, comparison, biginteger, bigdecimal

I want to compare a `BigInteger` with a `BigDecimal`. For example, the integer `10` should be equal to the decimal `10.0`.

Why does the following return false? I am creating a new decimal from the integer, and then comparing the two decimals.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(10)).equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.0)));
```

This returns true:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(10)).equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(10)));
```

How can I correctly compare a `BigInteger` with a `BigDecimal` in the mathematical/human definition (10 == 10.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BigInteger and BigDecimal you should use the compareTo method to check if their value is the same

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(10)).compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.0)));
```